# Why cant I configure POD-level securityContext settings to be applied to all underlying Containers?

Tags: kubernetes, security-context, podsecuritypolicy

In my POD, I wanted to restrict ALL my containers to read-only file systems with
***securityContext: readOnlyRootFilesystem: true***
example (note: yaml reduced for brevity)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:      
  labels:
    run: server123
  name: server123
spec:
  securityContext:
    readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  containers:
  - image: server1-image
    name: server1 
  - image: server2-image
    name: server2
  - image: server3-image
    name: server3
```

this will result in:

> error: error validating "server123.yaml": error validating data:
> ValidationError(Pod.spec.securityContext): unknown field
> "readOnlyRootFilesystem" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSecurityContext; if
> you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with
> --validate=false

instead I have to configure as:

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:      
      labels:
        run: server123
      name: server123
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: server1-image
        name: server1
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true 
      - image: server2-image
        name: server2
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      - image: server3-image
        name: server3
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

Is there a way to set this security restriction ONCE for all containers?
If not why not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Kubernetes, can configure ***securityContext*** at pod and/or container level,
containers would inherit pod-level settings, but can override in their own.

The configuration options for pods and containers do not, however, overlap - you can only set specific ones at each level,
Container level: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#securitycontext-v1-core
Pod level: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#podsecuritycontext-v1-core

Its not documented clearly what can be inherited and what cannot (and why!). You have to read through both lists and compare.
I would assume that POD's securityContext would allow, say, ***readOnlyRootFilesystem: true*** and various ***capabilities***, to be set once and not have to be replicated in each underlying container's securityContext, but **PodSecurityContext** does not allow this!

Would be particularly useful when (re)configuring various workloads to adhere to PodSecurityPolicies.

I wonder why a Pod's ***securityContext*** configuration is labelled as such, and not instead as ***podSecurityContext***, which is what it actually represents.

Answer (score 1):

This requirement demands a policy implementation and this is possible using pod security policy. [Please read here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#volumes-and-file-systems).

There is a dedicated restriction control specified - *"Requiring the use of a read only root file system"*.

Note: This is going to be [deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/06/podsecuritypolicy-deprecation-past-present-and-future/) in v1.25.x with a new technology. So please plan for it.

Comment: My question is independent of pod security policy enforcement, and more about clarity of PodSecurityContext to (Container)SecurityContext inheritence. There is no way to set multiple containers to having ReadOnlyRootFilesystem by making one single configuration at parent pod level